# NLTK sentiment towards entity

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, named-entity-extraction

I have just started using NLTK and the task I need to accomplish is pretty simple, I think.
I need to parse a number of documents and extract the sentiment towards some entities. For example the overall sentiment of the following sentence:

```
Tea is great. However, I hate coffee.
```

is negative, but I would like to extract the sentiment towards single, predefined entities. In particular, in the previous example I would like to feed NLTK with my entities `('tea', 'coffee')` and be able to extract `sentiment('tea')` and `sentiment('coffee')` separately.
I read through [this](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) document but I could not find a way to accomplish this simple task.

Comment: Your example includes two sentences, not one, and sentiment analysis is an open area of research, especially if you're hoping to extract sentiment at the level of whole documents.

Comment: @dmh, why so pessimistic? Common methods of sentiment analysis are so crude that it really doesn't matter if you apply them to a sentence or to a text. E.g., there's no syntactic analysis involved-- it's mostly bag-of-words classification.

Comment: I suppose I assumed @Simone was looking for a better approach without actually asking if a bag-of-words baseline would be good enough for their application. Sorry if my comment was discouraging and unhelpful, @Simone!

Comment: Don't worry @dmh, it's fine, I know I am entering a tricky path and I am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Could you please share some resources about this requirement & how did you accomplished it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [classifier](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html), and you need an annotated sentiment corpus to train it with. The nltk offers the `movie_review` corpus, but of course you'll get best results if you train with something similar to your own data. See also the nltk's [nltk.sentiment](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.sentiment.html) package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointers (and the "optimism" (; )! I'll probably follow up with more questions while diving into this framework!